# How to prove that $\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)_{n\geq 1}$ is a null sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to prove that  $\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)_{n\geq 1}$ is a null sequence?

**My attempt via induction:**

If I prove that the denominator grows faster than the numerator, I can conclude that it is indeed a null sequence, right? So I have to show that $\sqrt{n}\geq (-1)^n$ for $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}:n\geq 1$

Base case with $n_0=1$: $\sqrt{1}=1\geq (-1)^1=-1 \quad \checkmark$

Induction hypothesis: $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}:\sqrt{n}\geq (-1)^n$

Induction claim: $\Longrightarrow  \sqrt{n+1} \geq (-1)^{n+1}$

Inductive step: $$\begin{gather}\sqrt{n+1}\geq (-1)^{n+1} \quad |\cdot (-1)  \\ -\sqrt{n+1}\leq (-1)^{n+2} \end{gather}$$ This is true, since $-\sqrt{n+1}$ can't be $\geq -1$.

Is that a valid proof?

Comment: What's a "null sequence"? I'm not familiar with the term.

Comment: Presumably a sequence tending to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have $n+1\geqslant n$ for each $n$, but $\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is *not* a null sequence.

Note that $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\left\lvert\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}\right\rvert=\frac1{\sqrt n}$ and that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt n}=0$. This proves that your sequence is a null sequence.

Comment: So I just have to find the limit?

Comment: If you prove that the limit is $0$ then you shall have proved that the sequence is a null sequence.

Comment: Let's get a little crazy. How would I then prove the $\left(\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)_{n \geq 0}$ is a null sequence. L'Hopitals Rule hasn't been taught yet.

Comment: That's another question. Please post it as such.

Comment: Will do. Thanks.

Comment: Lol, can't: "You've asked 2 questions recently, some of which have not been received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account from asking questions entirely. "

Comment: Well, at least this last question of yours *was* well received. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I seriously don't know what's wrong with my first question... ?

Comment: Don't put “I don't even know how to start” or something similar in a question. Try *something* and display your effort.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Hello again, do you need any proof to know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt n}=0$. In the lecture this has been proven for $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n}=0$. Could I argue like that: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\left[\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \right]^{\frac{1}{2}}=0^{\frac{1}{2}}=0$

Comment: That looks fine to me.

Comment: Further inquiry: Why do you use $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\left\lvert\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}\right\rvert=\frac1{\sqrt n}$ to prove that the limit is 0?

Comment: Because $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt n}=\frac1\infty=0$. This argument doesn't work for the original sequence.

Comment: But why does showing $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt n}=\frac1\infty=0$ imply that the limit of $\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)_{n\geq 1}$ is also equal to $=0$?

Comment: Because $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0\iff\lim_{n\to\infty}\lvert a_n\rvert=0$.

Comment: Ah, yesss!!!!!! Thank you so much.

Comment: Is that also a valid proof? Let $\varepsilon >0$. Furthermore, there exists a $N\in \mathbb{N}$ with $N>\frac{1}{\varepsilon ^2}$. Let $n\geq N$ be arbitrary. Then: $\left\lvert\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}\right\rvert=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}< \varepsilon$

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: :-), I think I understand it now!